# Automatic deployment from bitbucket repository to aws ec2 server

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

May be this was a simple question,but i didn't get a proper solution for my probelm.

I've an ec2 instance running in aws cloud(amazon ami with php and nginx),and the source code hosted in a bit bucket private repository.

Here is my current deployment process.

1.Login into my ec2 instance using ssh.

2.Deploy the source code with `git clone <remote-repo-url>`.

need to login every time into my ec2 instance ,ithink this is a bad practice.

Is there any way to simplify so that i can able to deploy to ec2 instance without login into my ec2 instance.

Amazon is providing a solution(AWS codedeploy) but its look like complex process also the documentation is difficult to understand.

One more question

I'am using `composer` to install and manage my php application so when i commit to repo i've excluded the `vendors` folder to `.gitignore`.

So when deploy server  i need to install `composer` and run `composer install` for the `vendors` folder(because `vendors` is excluded from git).

One way to overcome this is add `vendors` folder to `git`, but don't think its a good practice.

Is any way to avoid the `composer` installation in server and manage the `vendors` folders  in server without adding `vendors` folder to git.

Comment: why don't you use bitbucket?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found an answer for my first part(Automatic git deployment).

[this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) simply explains how to setup github automatic deployment 
in server.